# Finding average area of data in a csv file column

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns, area

I am having trouble creating a function on this code that I feel should be fairly easy. I have a CSV file called `tree_data.csv` with multiple columns labeled `tree_id`, `continent_data`, `tree_name`, `tree_location`, and `tree_area`. I am trying to collect all of the data in the `tree_area` column and return the total area as a float.

Not sure how to calculate area and the examples here only had a single list, and I'm not sure how to select a specific column in the CSV file. Here is what the data looks like:

| tree_area |
| --- |
| 0.53 |
| 0.32 |
| 0.14 |
| 0.53 |
| 0.62 |
| 0.84 |

There are a lot of cells and some of them are also blank, I'm not sure how to write their areas as being 0.

Comment: If you read in the data to a Pandas DataFrame using the read_csv function then selecting columns or rows is easy and calculations can be done. Blank cells would be OK. You don't provide enough information to comment much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the total `tree_area` like this:

```py
import csv
file = 'test.csv'

with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(file)
    total = 0
    for lines in csv_file:
        try:
            total += float(lines[4])
        except:
            pass

print(f"Total: {total}")
```

Result: `Total: 2.98`